# Android Paint: paint.setColor is not working when set paint.setShader together

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I have set paint.setColor to set paint color and paint.setShader() to set bitmap on paint but when i set the paint.setShader also along with paint.setColor, paint background color gone and just able to see the image only

here is my sample code:

```
    paint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));// working 

    //setting the bitmap on paint but the result is only bitmap only previously set paint.setColor is not working and the path on canvas shows only bitmap without paint color 
    Drawable drawable = dataSet.getBackgroundDrawable();                    
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

I want to achieve paint with background color and add transparent image on that paint area both together.

Comment: Paint `setColor` and Paint `setShader` don't work together. To use the shader, you need to set the color to -1. However, it sounds like you want the color and the shader together, in which case you may be looking to do something like using a PorterDuffColorFilter.